# How to extends downloadable product type?

Tags: product, downloadable, extend, custom-product-type

I am learning Magento and I am trying to create a Custom Product Type which can be download and provide some other features. I think I must start by extending the Downloadable product type. However I don't know how to do it. Where should I start and what I should do?

Please help. Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a downloadable product type. With attribute set and some attributes. Extends downloadable product type is not necessary.

Show http://growwithtrellis.com/blog/managing-attributes-attribute-sets-magento-1-9/ for example

Comment: thank you a lot! But what if my would like to extend the downloadable product type? Is it possible and how to do it?

Comment: See http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-a-custom-product-type-in-magento--cms-21014